# How to split a list into parts and don't loose the last entries

Tags: list, language-agnostic, split

how can I split a list(e.g. 24 entries) into several parts(each containing max. 10 entries) and cover the last entries?

What I have done so far:

```
 //init list
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    List<Integer> splitted = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        splitted.add(list.get(i));
        if(i != 0 && i % 10 == 0) {
            //print splitted list
            System.out.println(splitted);
            splitted.clear();
        }
    }
```

That works for the entries 0-20 but the entries 21,22,23 and 24 will not appear in any list. How can I fix this? Because `i % 10 == 0` won't work for them.

Comment: Sorry ... What do you mean by "cover"?

Comment: @belisarius The last 4 entries won't appear in any list.

Comment: Do you want _EQUAL SIZED_ parts?

Comment: Almost, but not for the last entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work or at leart give you some idea. What I do is first check whether list is finished or splitted reached 10. Then check if i is not equal to 0 and print splitted.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    splitted.add(list.get(i));
    if(i==list.size()-1 || i%10==0) {
       if(i!=0){
          //print splitted list
           System.out.println(splitted);
           splitted.clear();
       }
    }
}
```